# Kivy: Add textinputs when a value is selected on a spinner

Tags: python, kivy, spinner, kivy-language, textinput

I've tried something like this, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.
(In addition, I don't get how to place the textinput under the spinner)

Python file :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    pass

class MyApp(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def choice(self, spinnerChoice):
        if spinnerChoice == '1':
            self.ids.spinnerid.add_widget(MyTextInput(hint_text='Enter value'))
        if spinnerChoice == '2':
            self.ids.spinnerid.add_widget(MyTextInput(hint_text='Enter value'))

class MainWindow(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyApp()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow().run()
```

Kivy file :

```
<MyApp>:
GridLayout:
    cols: 3

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: lab1
            text: "label 1"
        TextInput:
            id: tp1

        Spinner:
            id: spinnerid
            on_text: root.choice(spinnerid.text)
            values: ['1', '2']
            size_hint:(.4,.4)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        Label:
            id: lab1
            text: "label 2"
        TextInput:
            id: tp2
        Label:
            text: "State :"
        CheckBox:
            id: cb
            size_hint:(.5,.5)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
```

I'm working with a kivy file and I wanted to add some text inputs when a value on a spinner is selected.
For example, if the value of the spinner is '2', it will add a textinput wondering the value of 2.

Comment: Your code has several syntax errors. Please post a [mcve] that is runnable.

Comment: You were right. I've changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is adding `MyTextInput`, but the code:

```
self.ids.spinnerid.add_widget(MyTextInput(hint_text='Enter value'))
```

is adding a new `MyTextInput` to the `Spinner`. I suspect that you don't want to add the `MyTextInput` to the `Spinner`, so I suggest modifying part of your `kv` file to:

```
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
```

to add an `id` to the `BoxLayout`. Then change the line that adds the `MyTextInput` to:

```
self.ids.box.add_widget(MyTextInput(hint_text='Enter value'))
```

so that the `MyTextInput` is added to the `BoxLayout`.

Comment: I didn't know we could put an id on a boxlayout. Thank you, that's what I was looking for !